# (java) Какие есть фреймворки для создания веб-приложений

Tags: java

Какие есть java фреймворки для создания веб-приложений
Желательно современные

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Тут не место таким вопросам. Вы вполне можете сами найти нужные вам фреймворки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря, что считать web приложением. На самом деле "классические" web приложения сейчас на Java уже никто (или почти никто) не пишет. На Java сейчас пишут backend, а это не совсем web. Хотя бы потому, что к backend API может обращаться любой клиент, а не только web интерфейс.

Раньше использовали в основном сервлеты, JSP/JSF и Spring MVC в сочетании JSP/JSF и т.п.

Никто не запрещает Вам использовать всё это и сейчас. Но, такой подход (применительно к Java) в наши дни уже очень сильно устарел.